# how to detect changes to an element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im using selenium to automate a test.

so i have an element that is changed by javascript.  how can i detect a change to the text of that item?  for example, here is the html of the item before and after it's change:

before:

```
<span id="errorMsg"></span>
```

after:

```
<span id="errorMsg">All fields not filled out</span>
```

this is a current helper function i have that i call after clicking the submit button.  it works very well when loading new pages but it doesn't work in this scenario.

```
   public void waitforText(String search) {
        WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(Grid.driver(), Grid.getNewTimeOut() / 1000L);
        ExpectedCondition conditionToCheck = new ExpectedCondition() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
                WebElement bodyTag = Grid.driver().findElement(By.tagName("body"));
                return Boolean.valueOf(bodyTag.getText().contains(search));
            }
        };
        myWait.until(conditionToCheck);
    }
```

and how im calling the function:

```
waitforText("All fields not filled out");
```

i can see the message changed in the page but selenium does not detect this.  i know i can use a direct sleep or wait instead but i really do not want to go this route if it can be avoided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`textToBePresentInElement` expected condition](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("errorMsg"), "All fields not filled out"));
```